# Continuous Functions Proofs

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

If f and g are continuous at a, then f + g is continuous at a.

I have approached this where (1) (f+g)(x) and (2) c.f(x) are continuous wherever they are defined.

Example: H(x) = 3x^2 - x + 10
Therefore x^2, x and 10 are continuous as they are power functions.
3(x^2) and -(x) are continuous from proposition (2)
H(x) is continuous by proposition (1).
Therefore (f+g)(x) is continuous at any point a.

Please may someone help me with this, as I'm unsure whether my answer actually proves the first statement?

Comment: You can't prove something by using a particular example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$ then we have $\vert f(x)-f(a) \vert$ < $\epsilon_1$ as $\vert x-a\vert<\delta_1$ and $\vert g(x)-g(a)\vert <\epsilon_2$ when $\vert x-a\vert<\delta_2$.

So, when we have $(f+g)$ to be our function we have $$\vert (f+g)(x)-(f+g)(a)\vert<\vert f(x)-f(a)+g(x)-g(a)\vert<\vert f(x)-f(a)\vert+\vert g(x)-g(a)\vert<\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$$
put $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2 = \epsilon$ as the choice of $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we have $$\vert (f+g)(x)-(f+g)(a)\vert<\epsilon$$ whenever $\vert x-a\vert <\delta$ and then we can choose the $\delta$ to be $\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, this really helps